# Yii2 form submission fails in the first attempt but works in the second attempt after clearing the web browser history

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to make a login form using active forms in yii2 framework. It works fine and take the user to the dashboard. But, after clearing the history and all from my browser, it says "Bad Request, Unable to Submit Your Form Data". And in the second attempt, It logs me in. What could be the problem here. 
**This is my controller**.

```
public function actionIndex(){

        $model = new LoginForm();
        $Session= Yii::$app->session;

        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        } 
        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()){

            $Data = Yii::$app->request->post();

            $username = $Data['LoginForm']['username']; 

            $adminDetail = RegisterForm::find()
                        ->where(['username'=>$username])
                        ->all();      

            $id= $adminDetail[0]['id'];
            $adminName= $adminDetail[0]['name'];
            $username= $adminDetail[0]['username'];
            $phone= $adminDetail[0]['phone'];
            $email= $adminDetail[0]['email'];
            $lastName= $adminDetail[0]['lastName'];
            $bio= $adminDetail[0]['bio'];
            $city= $adminDetail[0]['city'];
            $dob= $adminDetail[0]['date_of_birth'];
            $status= $adminDetail[0]['status'];

            $Session->set('id', $id);
            $Session->set('id', $id);
            $Session->set('username', $username);

            if($status==0){

                Yii::$app->user->logout();

                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('Disallow', 'Your membership has been expired.</n> <a href="#">Please Click Here To Upgrade</a>');
                $this->redirect(array('/'));
            }

            return $this->redirect(['/dashboard']);

        }

        if($Session->get('id')){
            $find= RegisterForm::find()
            ->where(['id'=>$Session->get('id')])
            ->all();

            $adminName= $find[0]['name'];
            return $this->render('adminLogin',[
                'model'=>$model,
                'Session'=> $Session,
                'adminName'=>$adminName,
            ]);
        }
        else{

            return $this->render('adminLogin',[
                'model'=>$model,
                'Session'=> $Session,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**This is my view File**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([

                            'id' => 'login-form login-username login-password login-remember-me',
                            'layout' => 'horizontal',
                             'options' => ['class' =>['form-horizontal push-30-t push-50

                                '],

                                ],

                        ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox([

    ]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Below is the image of the first attempt**
[image]

**Here is the second attempt**
[image]

Comment: is it happening on every form submission can you verify the default Contact Us form provided by Yii does it happen with that form too.

Comment: posted an answer for you see if that helps you out

Answer (score 0):

This happens mostly due to `csrf` validation.

First, try to verify if it is happening on every form on your site. Verify by using default contact us form provided by yii framework try to submit it and see if it happens with that form too.

Then check that the layout file you are using contains the line

```
<?= Html::csrfMetaTags () ?>
```

If not, update your main layout file by adding this line in the `<head>` section. This change is needed because `yii\web\View` no longer automatically generates `CSRF` meta tags due to [`issue #3358`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/UPGRADE.md#upgrade-from-yii-20-beta).

If still cannot resolve remove cache and delete cookies from your browser and try again.

If still the same then you can turn off CSRF validation for the specific controller like below

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    \Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;    
}
```

or for a specific action in `beforeAction()`

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeAction($action)
{            
    if ($action->id == 'my-method') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```